# VirtualBox - no sound on Lubuntu 18.10 on Mac OSX host

Tags: macos, ubuntu, audio, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I don't hear any sound on Lubuntu 18.10 run in VirtualBox (Version 6.0.0 r127566 (Qt5.6.3)) on Mac OS High Sierra.

My config:

VirtualBox:
[image]

Lubuntu 18.10:
[image]
[image]

Is it a bug or I missed something in my config?

Comment: could you give a try to these instructions first https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/

Comment: @andilabs when I turn some sound on Lubuntu I see the volume meter is moving: https://imgur.com/a/o4C1hDM so it looks like it is muted on Mac OSX level?

Comment: This is not a programming question - it should be closed but it has a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Disable and re-Enable Audio then restart system.
That solved my sound problem.